# compiling libtorrent Rasterbar for mavericks

Tags: python, c++, boost, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I just compiled and installed boost from source using

`$pwd`

`/Downloads/boost_1_58_0`

`./b2 threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++"`

and got message after build completed,

The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

```
/Downloads/boost_1_58_0
```

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

```
/Downloads/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib
```

now that I was trying to install lib torrent's python pending using `sudo pip install .`

I got error message `b2: command not found` since I knew where the b2 command was in my location from where I build boost, i updated setup.py to the specific path,

but still when I try to `sudo pip install .` python binding of lib torrent I get below message.

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find "boost-build.jam"
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    BOOST_ROOT must be set, either in the environment, or
    on the command-line with -sBOOST_ROOT=..., to the root
    of the boost installation.

    Attempted search from /private/tmp/pip-OWjwyj-build up to the root
    at /Downloads/share/boost-build
    and in these directories from BOOST_BUILD_PATH and BOOST_ROOT: /usr/share/boost-build.
    Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
    /Downloads/boost_1_58_0/b2 boost=source link=static geoip=static boost-link=static release optimization=space stage_module --abbreviate-paths -j4
    build failed

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-OWjwyj-build
```

after following the steps mentioned in first answer I tried to run `make` but it gave following error:

```
In file included from ../include/libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp:55:
../include/libtorrent/storage.hpp:346:3: error: no template named 'scoped_ptr'
      in namespace 'boost'; did you mean 'boost::asio::detail::scoped_ptr'?
                boost::scoped_ptr<storage_interface> m_storage;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                boost::asio::detail::scoped_ptr
/opt/local/include/boost/asio/detail/scoped_ptr.hpp:27:7: note:
      'boost::asio::detail::scoped_ptr' declared here
class scoped_ptr
      ^
In file included from piece_picker.cpp:41:
In file included from ../include/libtorrent/aux_/session_impl.hpp:66:
In file included from ../include/libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp:55:
../include/libtorrent/storage.hpp:279:53: error: no viable overloaded
      'operator->'
                error_code const& error() const { return m_storage->error(); }
                                                         ~~~~~~~~~^
/opt/local/include/boost/asio/detail/scoped_ptr.hpp:49:6: note: candidate
      function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      boost::scoped_ptr<storage_interface>', but method is not marked const
  T* operator->()
     ^
In file included from piece_picker.cpp:41:
In file included from ../include/libtorrent/aux_/session_impl.hpp:66:
In file included from ../include/libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp:55:
../include/libtorrent/storage.hpp:280:59: error: no viable overloaded
      'operator->'
  ...std::string const& error_file() const { return m_storage->error_file(); }
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~^
/opt/local/include/boost/asio/detail/scoped_ptr.hpp:49:6: note: candidate
      function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      boost::scoped_ptr<storage_interface>', but method is not marked const
  T* operator->()
     ^
In file included from piece_picker.cpp:41:
../include/libtorrent/aux_/session_impl.hpp:624:4: error: no template named
      'scoped_ptr' in namespace 'boost'; did you mean
      'boost::asio::detail::scoped_ptr'?
                        boost::scoped_ptr<boost::thread> m_thread;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        boost::asio::detail::scoped_ptr
/opt/local/include/boost/asio/detail/scoped_ptr.hpp:27:7: note:
      'boost::asio::detail::scoped_ptr' declared here
class scoped_ptr
      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't seem to mind using boost-build to build, the simplest way to do it is to:

```
export BOOST_ROOT=/Downloads/boost_1_58_0
export BOOST_BUILD_PATH=$BOOST_ROOT/tools/build
export PATH=$PATH:$BOOST_BUILD_PATH/src/engine/bin.macosxx86_64
echo "using darwin ;" >~/user-config.jam

cd libtorrent/bindings/python
b2 boost=source
```

The first 4 lines is basically installing boost-build (`b2`). It's assuming the output directory when you built b2 was bin.macosxx86_64.

That will build the libtorrent python module, it won't install it though.

Comment: sorry but that didn't help, I followed the above steps then tried to `make` `libtorrent` but running make gives 
`4 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [piece_picker.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1`

I have updated that part in the post since those error were too big to post here

Comment: those instructions did not include running ``make``. Do you get compilation errors or link errors? if it's not finding boost, you may have to pass in --with-boost=... to the configure script. see ``./configure --help``